# Micropython building external C module

Tags: python, unix, module, micropython

So after changes in official micropython repository and due to incompatibility of older esp-idf versions I can't build external C modules no more. I followed the exact steps from this official documentation:
https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/develop/cmodules.html

I am running this command inside /ports/unix folder:

```
USER_C_MODULES=../../../modules CFLAGS_EXTRA=-DMODULE_EXAMPLE_ENABLED=1 all
```

The error I get is:

```
Use make V=1 or set BUILD_VERBOSE in your environment to increase build verbosity.
Including User C Module from ../../../modules/example
make: *** No rule to make target 'example/python/micropython/my_project/modules/example/example.c', needed by 'build-standard/genhdr/qstr.i.last'.  Stop.
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need 2 `micropyhon.cmake` files. 1 should be in your root `modules` directory and act as a master include for all your modules that you want to include in the compile. The 2nd one should be in your specific module directory. If you have more than one module to include you will need a `micropython.cmake` file in each one. These are used to include all the source code to be compiled.

Once you have the proper `cmake` files you can compile by changing your directory to the appropriate `micropython/ports/DesiredPort` subdirectory and using the command line:

`make USER_C_MODULES=/path/to/your/modules/micropython.cmake all`

You can find examples at the following link.

https://github.com/micropython/micropython/tree/master/examples/usercmodule